# JavaScript statements not getting executed after jquery function

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have the following HTML

```
<form onsubmit="call_it()" action="listing.php" method="get">
```

In the called function the `alert('3')` is not getting called. The jQuery `each` function is working perfectly but not sure why nothing is getting executed after that.

```
function call_it() {
  alert('2');

  $('.form_field').each(function(i, obj) {
    if (this.value == "") {
      document.getElementById(this.id + '_blank').style.display = "block";
    }
  });

  alert('3');
  ///other statements
}
```

Comment: What do you see in the dev tools?

Comment: Have you checked the console for errors?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]

Comment: actually I am calling this on <form onsubmit="call_it()" action="listing.php" method="get">. So the page is getting to listing.php. So I am not able to see the console log.

Comment: @Monty no! no no!!! (think steve carell gif) - no inline js!

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs : So what should I do here ? But Is there anything wrong in this?]

Comment: it is crashing here.. document.getElementById(this.id + '_blank').style.display = "block";

Comment: @Monty place the function in a script and call it from the script. There is a lot wrong with it, it makes it 1000x harder to manage any code. Keep the languages separate!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I am calling this on `<form onsubmit="call_it()" action="listing.php" method="get">`

In this case the issue is because the form is actually being submit. Hence the page is unloaded, and all JS processing is cancelled, before `alert('3')` is reached.

To fix this, first remove the outdated `on*` event handler and use unobtrusive JS to attach your event handlers, and secondly, stop the form submission if the validation fails. Try this:

```
<form action="listing.php" method="get" id="theForm">
  <!-- HTML inputs here... -->
</form>
```

```js
$('#theForm').submit(function(e) {
  alert('2');

  $('.form_field').each(function(i, obj) {
    if (!this.value) {
      e.preventDefault();
      $('#' + this.id + '_blank').show();
    }
  });

  alert('3');
});
```

[**Working example**](https://jsfiddle.net/c4k1r4cg/)

Comment: BRB, building a fiddle example as someone obviously doesn't believe me

Comment: yeah no idea for downvote (we'll hunt you down and make you upvote xD)

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs that makes absolutely no difference to compatibility. `submit()` calls `on('submit', fn)` internally

Comment: I didn't DV, but you gotta know this is a duplicate question...

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs there's no difference between the two other than another function nesting. there's nothing "better" about it.

Comment: @MikeMcCaughan you're probably right, although I couldn't find a suitable one. If you can link one I'll Mjolnir this question

Comment: Excellant @RoryMcCrossan Its working fine. Thanks a ton mate.

Comment: Already VtC :).

Comment: Yep, just noticed it tucked away :) @Monty no problem, glad to help

Comment: still waiting to see fiddle.... I would have expected this function to run to completion (thus alerting both times) since you can return false to an onsubmit= to cancel a submit.

Comment: @KevinB sure you can do that too, but OP wasn't. Here's the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/c4k1r4cg/, and this is OPs original displaying the described behaviour where `alert('3')` is skipped: https://jsfiddle.net/4wjr00sh/

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs there isn't one. If you want event delegation, you use .on. Doesn't make it better than .submit for non-event delegation.

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan right... but...  even if you're not returning, the function has to complete to see what the return value is... the submission hasn't started yet at that point, whether you're returning or not. I'd suspect the user is actually getting an error inside the .each, or a jquery is not defined error.

Comment: Yeah, that's pretty much it. `on()` can be delegated, whereas the shortcut event handlers (`click()`, `mouseup()`, `submit()` etc) cannot

Comment: Great thanks :) will delete my comments :D

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan you mean... the fact that it's submitting due to jquery not being defined? here i clearly get both alerts: https://jsfiddle.net/4wjr00sh/2/

Comment: @KevinB I am a moron. The amount of times I forget to include a library in a fiddle isn't even funny. Well I'm not sure about the OPs case then, but he claims this did solve the problem. Perhaps there was another event handler which immediately caused the form submission then.